# How to symmetrically split a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to symmetrically split a string in JavaScript. By that I mean, if it is 8 characters, then divide it into chunks of 2. If it is 9 characters, into chunks of 3. If it is n characters, divide it into chunks of 2 and 3 so that it forms a mirror image in the center.

```
const segmentNumber = (value) => {
  let array = value.split('')
  if (array.length % 3 === 0) {
    return chunkArray(array, 3).join('·')
  } else if (array.length % 2 === 0) {
    return chunkArray(array, 2).join('·')
  } else {
    let reversed = array.slice().reverse()
    let a = 0
    let ar = []
    let zr = []
    while (true) {
      ar.push(array.slice(a, a + 2).join(''))
      zr.push(reversed.slice(a, a + 2).join(''))
      array = array.slice(a + 2)
      reversed = reversed.slice(a + 2)
      a += 2
      let modulus
      if (array.length % 3 === 0) {
        modulus = 3
      } else if (array.length % 2 === 0) {
        modulus = 2
      }
      if (modulus) {
        return ar.concat(chunkArray(array, modulus)).concat(zr.reverse())
      }
    }
  }

  return
}

function chunkArray(arr, len) {

  var chunks = [],
      i = 0,
      n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return chunks;
}
```

I can chunk the string but not sure how to make it symmetrically chunked. For example:

- 10: 2-3-3-2
- 11: 2-2-3-2-2
- 12: 3-3-3-3
- 13: 2-3-3-3-2

How do you generate this sort of pattern, where the smaller numbers are on the outside, and the bigger number 3 is toward the center, so it forms a mirror image?

How do I improve what I am sort of implementing?

Comment: Chunk into pairs (2) then rematch as many of them as possible so that you've got the desired output.

Comment: is it only ever going to be 3's and 2's?

Comment: This is a quite vague question. It's not clear what the input can be.

Comment: are there no restrictions like the most number of 3 should be chosen? as a certain length might have different combinations of symmetrical chunks. like 18 which can be 333333 and 22233222. And based on your samples above, it can be possible that it can produce only 3s

Comment: is it a case of as many 3's as you can, then an even number of 2's on the outside? because, that's a trivial problem

Comment: @Bravo, that may be the case i believe, optimizing the 3s inside then pad 2 outside if possible.

Comment: Yes it's only ever going to be 3's and 2s, though if you could make it sort of a triangle (large and larger numbers in the middle by 1), that would be really cool bonus. But yeah just 3's and 2's, mine is starting to get complex. 10·220·562·711·425·229·54.

Comment: huh? bigger numbers - you want a pascal triangle type of thing (obviously without the ones)?

Comment: Nevermind, just 2's and 3's is good.

Comment: Given time, I can do it ... would there be a constraint that you can't do things like `2-3-5-3-2` - i.e. you can't use a 5 if there's no 4? it's pretty simple really

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**a solver that solves by calling itself**

Recursion and generators are the natural solution to this problem. We can use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to write segment(t) for any number, t  -

1. If the input `t` is less than zero, there are no valid segments. Stop iteration
2. (inductive) `t` is non-negative. If `t` is zero, yield the empty segment, `[]`
3. (inductive) `t` is positive. Yield the singleton segment, `[t]`, and for each `i` of the range 1..`t`, for each segment `s` of the sub-problem `t - i * 2`, symmetrically prepend and append `i` to the segment and yield

```js
function* segment(t) {
  if (t < 0) return               // 1
  if (t == 0) return yield []     // 2
  yield [t]                       // 3
  for (let i = 1; i < t; i++)
    for (const s of segment(t - i * 2))
      yield [i, ...s, i]
}

console.log("== 7 ==")
for (const s of segment(7))
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
  
console.log("== 8 ==")
for (const s of segment(8))
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
== 7 ==
7
1 · 5 · 1
1 · 1 · 3 · 1 · 1
1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1
1 · 2 · 1 · 2 · 1
2 · 3 · 2
2 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 2
3 · 1 · 3
```

```
== 8 ==
8
1 · 6 · 1
1 · 1 · 4 · 1 · 1
1 · 1 · 1 · 2 · 1 · 1 · 1
1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1
1 · 1 · 2 · 2 · 1 · 1
1 · 2 · 2 · 2 · 1
1 · 2 · 1 · 1 · 2 · 1
1 · 3 · 3 · 1
2 · 4 · 2
2 · 1 · 2 · 1 · 2
2 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 2
2 · 2 · 2 · 2
3 · 2 · 3
3 · 1 · 1 · 3
4 · 4
```

**why `t - i * 2`?**

The sub-problem is `t - i * 2`, or `t` minus two `i`s. The subsequent yield expression is adding two `i` to the result, so they must be subtracted from the sub-problem in order to balance the equation -

```js
for (const s of segment(t - i * 2)) // subtract two i from t
  yield [i, ...s, i]                // add two i to the segment
```

**why recursive technique?**

The advantages to this approach are numerous -

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| static, arbitrary split sizes | ❌ |
| only 2's and 3's | ❌ |
| modulus arithmetic | ❌ |
| conditional variable assignments | ❌ |
| array `.slice` or `.reverse` | ❌ |
| hard-coded `.join` | ❌ |
| string-to-number conversion | ❌ |
| `parseInt` | ❌ |
| division and rounding | ❌ |
| every combination found | ✅ |
| two local variables | ✅ |
| two simple `if` conditions | ✅ |
| pause, resume, or cancel | ✅ |

**visualization**

Given `segment(4)` -

```
[4]                                  // t = 4

[1,            , 1]
    \        /
      ...[2]                         // t = 2

[1,                           , 1]
    \                       /
      ...[1,           , 1]
             \       /
               ...[]                 // t = 0

[2,           , 2]
    \       /
      ...[]                          // t = 0

[3,           , 3]
    \       /
      ...❌                         // t = -2
```

```
[4]
[1,2,1]
[1,1,1,1]
[2,2]
```

**change output ordering**

This does not require a surgical rewiring of the algorithm or adjustment in the way you think about the problem. By changing the order of the `yield` expressions, you change the order of the output -

```js
function* segment(t) {
  if (t < 0) return
  if (t == 0) return yield []
  for (let i = 1; i < t; i++)
    for (const s of segment(t - i * 2))
      yield [i, ...s, i]
  yield [t]   // ✅ yield singleton segment last
}

console.log("== 7 ==")
for (const s of segment(7))
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
== 7 ==
1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 1
1 · 1 · 3 · 1 · 1
1 · 2 · 1 · 2 · 1
1 · 5 · 1
2 · 1 · 1 · 1 · 2
2 · 3 · 2
3 · 1 · 3
7
```

**minimum segment length**

Perhaps you want the smallest segment to be `2` or `3`. By adding a `min` parameter, this can be decided by the caller instead of hard coding it into the `segment` function -

```js
function* segment(t, min = 0) { // ✅ add min parameter
  if (t < min) return              // ✅ t < min
  if (t == 0) return yield []
  for (let i = Math.max(1, min); i < t; i++) // ✅ max(1, min)
    for (const s of segment(t - i * 2, min)) // ✅ pass min
      yield [i, ...s, i]
  yield [t]
}

console.log("== 18 ==")
for (const s of segment(18, 3)) // ✅ segments of 3 or greater
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**maximum segment length**

In a similar fashion, a `max` parameter can be added to control the maximum segment length. Avoid hard-coding this in the function to retain increased flexibility for the caller -

```js
function* segment(t, min = 0, max = t) { // ✅ add max parameter
  if (t < min) return
  if (t == 0) return yield []
  for (let i = Math.max(1, min); i < t; i++)
    for (const s of segment(t - i * 2, min, max)) // ✅ pass max
      yield [i, ...s, i]
  if (t <= max) yield [t] // ✅ if (t <= max)
}

console.log("== 18 ==")
for (const s of segment(18, 3, 8)) // ✅ segments between 3 and 8
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
== 18 ==
3 · 3 · 6 · 3 · 3
3 · 4 · 4 · 4 · 3
4 · 3 · 4 · 3 · 4
5 · 8 · 5
6 · 6 · 6
7 · 4 · 7
```

**increasing toward the center**

If you would like the numbers to increase toward the center, that is a matter of adding yet another configurable parameter, `init`. As you can see, each nuanced criteria can be carefully added with only minor adjustments to the original algorithm -

```js
function* segment(t, min = 0, max = t, init = 1) { // ✅ init = 1
  if (t < min || t < init) return // ✅ || t < init
  if (t == 0) return yield []
  for (let i = Math.max(init, min); i < t; i++) // ✅ init
    for (const s of segment(t - i * 2, min, max, i + 1)) // ✅ i + 1
      yield [i, ...s, i]
  if (t <= max) yield [t]
}

console.log("== 36 ==")
for (const s of segment(36, 2, 9))
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
== 36 ==
2 · 3 · 4 · 5 · 8 · 5 · 4 · 3 · 2
2 · 5 · 7 · 8 · 7 · 5 · 2
3 · 4 · 7 · 8 · 7 · 4 · 3
3 · 5 · 6 · 8 · 6 · 5 · 3
```

**split the string**

To split a string we can write `split` which takes a string and a value returned by `segment` -

```js
const split = (t, [s, ...segments]) =>
  s == null
    ? []
    : [t.substring(0, s), ...split(t.substring(s), segments)]

function* segment(t) {
  if (t < 0) return
  if (t == 0) return yield []
  for (let i = 1; i < t; i++)
    for (const s of segment(t - i * 2))
      yield [i, ...s, i]
  yield [t]
}
    
const word = "function"
for (const s of segment(word.length)) // ✅ segment word.length
  console.log(split(word, s).join(" · ")) // ✅ split word using s
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
f · u · n · c · t · i · o · n
f · u · n · ct · i · o · n
f · u · nc · ti · o · n
f · u · ncti · o · n
f · un · c · t · io · n
f · un · ct · io · n
f · unc · tio · n
f · unctio · n
fu · n · c · t · i · on
fu · n · ct · i · on
fu · nc · ti · on
fu · ncti · on
fun · c · t · ion
fun · ct · ion
func · tion
function
```

**optimization**

You could speed up the algorithm by eliminating the check for some combinations. The outer `for` loop goes from 1..`t` but could be shortened to 1..`Math.floor(t/2)`. This improves the performance of `segment` but adds some complexity. For sake of clarity this was left out and remains an update for the reader.

**without generators**

Although generators are a great fit for combinatorics problems, they are not required. We can lift the entire program into an Array context and have `segment` return an array of results instead of an iterator. Notice the ergonomics are not as good and the data nesting level has forcibly been increased by one. It does however follow the same inductive reasoning as the original algorithm -

```js
function segment(t) {
  if (t < 0) return []            // if (t < 0) return 
  if (t == 0) return [[]]         // if (t == 0) return yield []
  return [                        //   
    [t],                          // yield [t]
    ...range(1, t).flatMap(i =>   // for (let i = 0; i<t; i++)
      segment(t - i * 2).map(s => //   for (const s of segment(t - i * 2))
        [[i, ...s, i]]            //     yield [i, ...s, i]
      )
    )
  ]
}

function range(a, b) {
  return Array.from(Array(b - a), (_, n) => n + a)
}

console.log("== 7 ==")
for (const s of segment(7))
  console.log(s.join(" · "))
```

```
== 7 ==
7
1,5,1
1,1,3,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,2,1,2,1
2,3,2
```

Comment: Awesome use of generators, I'm bookmarking this Q&A.

Comment: Awesome solutions!!! Now I wonder, how can the full "split the string" one be implemented in an imperative way without recursion or functional programming?

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your output? I am not sure with what your inputs are so I have only tested it on the sample values you provided instead.

```js
function segmentNumber(length) {
  let outside = 0;
  if (length < 6)
    return 'Only 6 and greater';

  if(length % 3 == 0) 
    return new Array(length / 3).fill(3).join('-');
  else {
    while(length % 3 != 0 && length > 6) {
      outside++;
      length = length - 4;
    }
    if(length == 4) 
      return new Array(Math.floor(++outside * 2)).fill(2).join('-');
    else
      return [...new Array(outside).fill(2), 
              ...new Array(Math.floor(length / 3)).fill(3), 
              ...new Array(outside).fill(2)].join('-');
  }
}

console.log(segmentNumber(10))
console.log(segmentNumber(11))
console.log(segmentNumber(12))
console.log(segmentNumber(13))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will produce pattern for numbers greater than 6, and always have at least one '2' on the outside (except 9)

```js
const splitter = n => {
  if (n < 7) {
    throw 'bad'
  }
  let twos = 0;
  let threes = Math.ceil(n / 3);
  // 9 is an edge case
  if (n !== 9) {
    let remain;
    do {
      --threes;
      remain = n - threes * 3;
    } while (remain % 4);
    if (threes < 0) {
      threes = n / 3;
      remain = 0;
    }
    twos = remain / 4;
  }
  return `${'2'.repeat(twos)}${'3'.repeat(threes)}${'2'.repeat(twos)}`.split('');
}
for (let i = 7; i < 50; ++i) console.log(i, splitter(i).join('-'))
```

hmmm, I see you don't have 2's in all your cases

Simple change ...

```js
const splitter = n => {
  if (n < 7) {
    throw 'bad'
  }
  let twos = 0;
  let threes = Math.floor(n / 3) + 1;
  // 9 is an edge case
  let remain;
  do {
    --threes;
    remain = n - threes * 3;
  } while (remain % 4);
  if (threes < 0) {
    threes = n / 3;
    remain = 0;
  }
  twos = remain / 4;
  return `${'2'.repeat(twos)}${'3'.repeat(threes)}${'2'.repeat(twos)}`.split('');
}
for (let i = 7; i < 50; ++i) console.log(i, splitter(i).join('-'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function segmentNumber(value)
{
  for (let i = 0; i <= value; i++)
  {
    d = (value - 3 * i)/4
    if (d >= 0 && d == parseInt(d))
    {
      return Array(d).fill(2).concat(Array(i).fill(3), Array(d).fill(2))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Criteria

From what I gathered from the OP and comments, the objective is return a symmetrical series of 2s and 3s from a given integer. So here's a few criteria I tried to follow:

- From the start and end of the result are the 2s then the 3s are positioned up to the center:

  ```
  10 => 2 3 3 2
  ```
- Numbers that shouldn't be accepted are numbers lower than 4 and 5 as well. So a limit will be set for anything less than 6 (4 is symmetrical but I didn't want to write extra code to include it)
- If the given number is odd, it will have a 3 in the center.

  ```
  11 => 2 2 3 2 2
  ```
- A symmetrical pattern only needs one half of a pattern to be built so divide the number by 2 (if odd parity subtract 3 before dividing by 2).

  ```
  if (int < 6) return "Must be an integer greater than 5";
  let parity = int & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even';
  if (parity === 'odd') {
    int = int - 3;
  }
  side = int / 2;
  ```
- Find how many iterations are needed to divide the number by 3 and then the remaining (if any) by 2.
- The remaining number can only be a 4, 2, or 0 in order to maintain symmetry. If the remaining number is 1, then the total number of iterations to divide by 3 should be one less and the remaining number 1 will be a 4.
- Two separate loops to run division by 3 and division by 2.

  ```
  let temp = Math.floor(side / 3);
  let rem = side % 3;
  if (rem === 1) {
    temp = temp - 1;
    rem = 4;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
    result.push(3);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < rem / 2; i++) {
    result.push(2);
  }
  ```
- Next, make a copy of the `result` array with `.slice(0)` and `.reverse()` it. If `parity` was `"odd"` then `unshift(3)` to the front of `result`. Finally `.concat()` the reversed array in front of the `result` array, and then `.join(' ')` it into a string.

  ```
  const left = result.slice(0).reverse();
  if (parity === 'odd') {
    result.unshift(3);
  }
  return left.concat(result).join(' ');
  ```

```js
// Utility function
const log = (data, str = true) => {
  if (!str) return console.log(data);
  return console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

const x23 = int => {
  let result = [];
  let side, odd;
  if (int < 6) return "Must be an integer greater than 5";
  let parity = int & 1 ? 'odd' : 'even';
  if (parity === 'odd') {
    int = int - 3;
  }
  side = int / 2;

  let temp = Math.floor(side / 3);
  let rem = side % 3;
  if (rem === 1) {
    temp = temp - 1;
    rem = 4;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
    result.push(3);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < rem / 2; i++) {
    result.push(2);
  }

  const left = result.slice(0).reverse();
  if (parity === 'odd') {
    left.push(3);
  }
  return left.concat(result).join(' ');
}

log('5: '+x23(5));
log('6: '+x23(6));
log('7: '+x23(7));
log('8: '+x23(8));
log('9: '+x23(9));
log('10: '+x23(10));
log('11: '+x23(11));
log('12: '+x23(12));
log('13: '+x23(13));
log('14: '+x23(14));
log('15: '+x23(15));
log('16: '+x23(16));
log('17: '+x23(17));
log('18: '+x23(18));
log('19: '+x23(19));
log('20: '+x23(20));
log('21: '+x23(21));
log('22: '+x23(22));
log('23: '+x23(23));
log('24: '+x23(24));
log('53: '+x23(53));
log('99: '+x23(99));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```